# Create an Array of multiple Arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-array

i have an object with some proprieties, arrays of classes or structs

I want to put those proprieties in an array so i can access them easily
 in TableDataSource ( because of section, indexpath etc.. )

I've tried writing this initialization

```
var dataStructure = Array<Any>()

    var tweet : Tweet?{
        didSet{
            dataStructure.removeAll()
            dataStructure.append(tweet?.media)
            dataStructure.append(tweet?.urls )
            dataStructure.append(tweet?.hashtags)
            dataStructure.append(tweet?.userMentions)


        }
    }
```

and then retrieving it

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    let arr = dataStructure[section] as? NSArray

    if arr != nil{
        println(arr!)
        return arr!.count
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

but the arr is always nil

maybe is because i'm casting to NSArray? but i can't cast to "Array"

media , urls , hastags, and userMentions are initialized in the "Tweet" class

```
public var media = [MediaItem]()
public var hashtags = [IndexedKeyword]()
public var urls = [IndexedKeyword]()
public var userMentions = [IndexedKeyword]()
```

so they are pretty normal arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is a few problems with your code:

1) `didSet` is not calling during init. This cause `dataStructure` array to be empty;

2) Are you sure that you need cast to `NSArray`? You can get count without it.

3) It's will be much better to use computed property in `Tweet` class to receive required data.

```
public class Tweet {
    public var media = [MediaItem]()
    public var hashtags = [IndexedKeyword]()
    public var urls = [IndexedKeyword]()
    public var userMentions = [IndexedKeyword]()

    public var dataStructure:[Any] {
        return [media, hashtags, urls, userMentions]
    }
}
```

Comment: 2) How ? selecting an item from dataStructure:[Any] will return an item of type Any , but it has not the method .count


3) nice suggestion :)

Comment: Yes, you are right about 2). Actually you need switch your mind from objective-c styled code. Swift is strictly typed language and obj-c manner will cause problems to you. I suggest you to conform all custom types to some protocol and work with this protocol.

Comment: never used obj  :)
i'll try to figure something :)

Comment: If answer helped you you can vote or even accept it.